# SSIS - validating a column using sql or udf

Tags: ssis

I am importing data from excel into a sql server database. During the import process I have to validate a date column. The validation and correction logic is already built in a sql server udf. If I pass in the date and couple of other columns to the udf, it gives me the valid date.

The logic in the udf is fairly complex and I don't want to maintain it again in SSIS. The udf is not just doing a lookup. It is more than that.

Is there any way for me to derive a new column using sql or udf epxressions?

Thanks in advance,
rkgSSIS

Answer (score 1):

The component you're looking for is the [OLE DB Command Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141138.aspx). For every row that passes through the component, it will make a call to the database with whatever you supply it with.

In your case, you'd be looking at something like

```
SELECT dbo.MyUdf(?, ?, ?) AS IsGood
```

and you'd wire up the various columns to the `?` by their 0 based ordinal position.

Comment: Would populating a staging table with Excel data and then running the UDF against the staging data in a different Data Flow Task be better performance wise when compared to `OLE DB Command`?

Comment: @siva It might make for an interesting blog post but I think the user is already going to be suffering due to the row by row nature of a scalar UDF. I don't think compounding that pain by calling it 10k times versus being evaluated 10k times in a single pass is going to make a difference in performance.

Comment: @billinkc Using the OLE DB Command in this case would mean 10k additional network hops. **That** would be the performance killer.

Comment: I was not able to call a parameterized udf in "OLE DB Command." I was able to hard code the parameters, but not able to map a column. I had to resort to wrapping the udf inside an sp with an output param returning the value.